# Pass function to component to be used as onClick on react

Tags: reactjs

I thought it was easier :) what´s the right way to pass a function to a component? btw this doesn´t work.

```
<MyComponent onClick={() => someFunction(1)} />

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const {onClick} = props

    return <button onClick={onClick}>click/button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should work. I've found a possible issue on your button code. Ensure you are closing well button tag `</button>` i think you miss `<`

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-feynman-g3hqc

I hope this help you